# LAG function in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the table of invoices, which looks like this:

```
Nr  Type   Dateofacc
1           01.01.2020
aaa   AG  
bbb   HB 
2           05.01.2020
sss   PA 
nnn   KK
```

The problem is, that I have empty [Dateofacc] in case of the diffrent products on the same invoice, which should be the same as the [Dateofacc] in the whole invoice, so when I use the SELECT it should look like this:

```
Nr  Type   Dateofacc
1           01.01.2020
aaa   AG    01.01.2020
bbb   HB    01.01.2020
2           05.05.2020
sss   PA    05.05.2020
nnn   KK    05.05.2020
```

and I don't know how to do this. I tried LAG function, but it just works for the first row, and not the second. I wrote sth like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC([Nr]) = 1 THEN [Dateofacc]
        ELSE LAG([Dateofacc]) OVER(ORDER BY [Nr])
    END
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want with the data you have presented.  Why not?  SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi) sets.  *The rows have no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.*

Your results seem to require an ordering.

If I assume that a column has the ordering, then you can do what you want using window functions.  Use one function to assign a "group" to each group of rows (presumably based on `type` being `NULL`).  Then spread the value through the group:

```
select i.*,
       max(Dateofacc) over (partition by grp) as imputed_Dateofacc
from (select i.*,
             sum(case when type is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from invoices i
     ) i;
```